# AI model for transitioning between states

Tags: models

I have no knowledge and background in AI. I am however interested in a task, and was wondering if there might be some AI models, which are suitable for this kind of tasks: imagine we have two (abstract) states A and B. What i want is a smooth and gradual and imperceptible transition from state A to state B. As a concrete example: imagine state A is one piece of music and state B is another piece of music, and the result of the transition would be a smooth transformation of the first piece into the second one.
(If any one knows about non-AI models for this task, I would very appreciate pointing to them too).

Comment: Whether or not there are suitable models or approaches for interpolating between the states as you describe them, depends critically on the nature of the states (what they represent in your case), and any constraints you have on the interpolation. In the music example, a simple model for interpolating between A and B is to gradually decrease volume of A whilst increasing volume of B. This is used very often (called a cross-fade in audio industry), but the general interim state is not usually "musical" in a stand-alone sense, and would not represent for example a mixed genre.

Comment: So to make your question easier to answer, it is better to ask about the specific thing you want with example states and what you would consider a reasonable middle state. Then it may be possible to answer with references to AI research that works in that problem domain and matches what you are looking for. Don't ask about music, unless you specifically want to work with music